# Angular: how to access to resources?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Angular, and would like to play with $resource. What is unclear for me is how resource element is created.

For instance:

```
var service = angular.module("apiService", ["ngResource"]).factory('User', 
   ['$resource',
      function($resource){
         return $resource('/users/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
   }]
);
```

I am expecting to have an access to a 'User' object, like this:

```
User.query();
```

But User is not defined. Is there a specific namespace where this object is defined?

What would be the minimum running sample to get this working? (not that angular.js and angular-resource.js are loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do pass success function in query.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, User){
    User.query(function(user){
        $scope.user = user; //call when return data
    });
})
```

Or you could also this by resolving $promise object of query

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, User){
    User.query().$promise.then(function(user){
        $scope.user = user; //call when return data
    });
})
```

Comment: The problem is that User is not defined at all!

Comment: @tomsoft did you injected the service in controller & inside you main module have you injected `apiService` module

Comment: that's probably the point. How should I do this? (I am fairly new to Angular and just run a fe tutorials)

Comment: angular.module('app',["apiService"]).controller

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to include "apiService", or User in your controller? 
This works:

```
angular.module("apiService", ["ngResource"]).factory('User', 
   ['$resource',
      function($resource){
         return $resource('/users/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
   }]
);

angular.module("testApp", ['apiService']).controller('Test', function($scope, User) {
    User.query();
});
```

Fiddle for ref: http://jsfiddle.net/thepeak/2sscyck9/